# Audience Targeting with SharePoint groups

Tags: groups

Can SharePoint groups be used for audience targeting or does it need to a different group type like, M365?

Answer (score 0):

No, SharePoint groups are not supported.

Link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-content-to-a-specific-audience-on-a-sharepoint-site-68113d1b-be99-4d4c-a61c-73b087f48a81

[image]